# Using boost move with an instance parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, move-semantics

I have a function that deals with a movable-only instance that is a wrapper around something else. That object provides means of access to the wrapped object and some checks which require it to be non-copyable. (Use case is a table of values, where the dtor of the wrapper should assert that all values were were accessed)

I defined a custom ctor from the wrapped type and implemented the move ctor/assignment.

However I'm getting an error due to an attempted copy: `error: 'Movable::Movable(Movable&)' is private within this context`

It works fine in C++11 but I need portability to C++03. How can I do this without an explicit instantiation of the wrapper and moving it into the function?

MWE:

```
#include <boost/move/move.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Movable{
    BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE(Movable)
public:
    int i;
    Movable(int j):i(j){}
    Movable(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) other) // Move constructor
        : i(boost::move(other.i))
    {}

    Movable& operator=(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) other) // Move assignment
    {
        if(this != &other)
            i = boost::move(other.i);
        return *this;
    }
};

void bar(Movable mov){
    mov.i = 22;
    std::cout << mov.i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bar(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I have tested you can skip moving part for rvalue and call `bar(Movable(5));` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4c6bbeb20334fc6

Comment: Well that is better. Any chance to avoid even that? I mean the non-explicit conversion operator/ctor is meant to avoid that noise.

Comment: Maybe there is some trick, I have not written too advanced code in C++03, but for me there shouldn't. You already have implicit conversion into `boost::rv<Movable>`with signature from my example and compiler cannot deduce implicit twice (that is: `5 -> Movable (5) -> boost::rv<Movable>(Movable(5))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the implicit conversion constructor interferes with the copy-constructor suppression.

Either use

```
Movable m(5);
bar(boost::move(m));
```

Or

```
bar(Movable(5));
```

To make sure that you select for the explicit constructor. Obviously, that means you can even mark it `explicit`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31f87e8c85787aed)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/move/move.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Movable{
    BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE(Movable)
public:
    int i;
    explicit Movable(int j):i(j){}
    Movable(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) other) // Move constructor
        : i(boost::move(other.i))
    {}

    Movable& operator=(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) other) // Move assignment
    {
        if(this != &other)
            i = boost::move(other.i);
        return *this;
    }
};

void bar(Movable mov){
    std::cout << mov.i << " ";
    mov.i = 22;
    std::cout << mov.i << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Movable m(5);
    bar(boost::move(m));

    bar(Movable(6));
}
```

Prints

```
5 22
6 22
```